# ¿Cómo se calculan dobles sumatorias en R?

Tags: r

Como se calculan doble sumatorias en R, se requiere de algún condicional.?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y como crear un [mcve], luego, con respecto a tu pregunta, te sugiero que la edites y agregues lo que has intentado hasta ahora y que dificultades has tenido. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

EL uso encadenado de for, es una manera a mi parecer mas de python, por el contrario la instauración de paquetes en R "deja de lado" este tipo de "old school coding" pasando en R al uso defunciones apply, sapply, vapply.. entre otras funciones, para mi lo mas óptimo y al estilo R sería:

```
# sumatoria simple
resultado <- lapply(1:5, function(x) x^2)
sum(resultado)
## [1] 55

# sumatoria encadenada
sum(sapply(1:20, function(x){sapply(1:5, function(y) {x^4/(3+y)})}) )
## [1] 639215.3
```

Es lo mas eficiente en R.

Answer (score 2):

La doble sumatoria no es más que sumar los casos de `i` desde 1 a 20 y `j` desde 1 a 5 en todas sus posibles combinaciones.

Por ejemplo, con una sumatoria simple como la siguiente:

[image: formula]

El resultado de esta sumatoria debe ser la suma de 1, 4, 9, 16 y 25, en total 55. Para reproducir esta sumatoria en R, se debe crear un bucle para poder iterar en los distintos valores de `i`. Como práctica, yo suelo crear un vector vacío para ir almacenando el resultado para cada caso y al final realizar la sumatoria:

```r
resultado <- vector()

for(i in 1:5){
  resultado <- c(resultado, i^2)
}

sum(resultado)
## [1] 55
```

Para crear una sumatoria doble, basta con crear un bucle doble y seguir la misma lógica:

```r
resultado <- vector()

for(i in 1:20){
  for(j in 1:5)
    resultado <- c(resultado,(i^4/(3+j)))
}

sum(resultado)
## [1] 639215.3
```

Comment: El modo en el concatenas elementos dentro del vector funciona bien cuando el número de elementos es pequeño, es mejor realizar modificaciones en un vector en el que ya hemos reservado todo el espacio disponible

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar se generan el conjunto total de componentes que van a ser sumados. En tu caso, se haría del siguiente modo:

```
i <- ( rep((1:20) ^ 4, 5) )
j <- rep(1:5 + 3, each = 20)
sum( i / j )
 # [1] 639215.3
```